# ValueError: Image is not numeric, but ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm trying to save a sci-kit image, but I'm getting the error:

ValueError: Image is not numeric, but ndarray.

Code:

```py
from skimage import *
import skimage.io
import skimage.morphology as morphology

def loadImage(f):
    return skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread(f))

img = img_as_bool(loadImage("images/metric_map_processed.PNG"))

imgSk = morphology.medial_axis(img)
skimage.io.imsave("medial.png", imgSk)
```

According to the [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave), the passed in array should be a ndarray, so why am I getting an error?

Comment: At which line is the error?

Comment: @Divakar Line 10, the one where I try to save it

Comment: Could you put that error against the code where you are getting the error? We can't see line numbers here.

Comment: @Divakar Hi, just realised the issue was due to the image being converted to binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just realised that my image was being converted to binary

Replacing

```
skimage.io.imsave("medial.png", imgSk)
```

with

```
skimage.io.imsave("medial.png", img_as_uint(imgSk))
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pixel type in `png` is uint8. And when you apply `img_as_bool` you get boolean array. And this mismatch of type generate error.

You need to convert it to `uint8`. As suggest Alex use `img_as_uint` function.